# How to explain the behavior of 'Abc123P'.istitle() in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I cannot understand the return result of 'istitle()' method of Python marked as 'Incomprehensible' below:

```
>>> # Comprehensible
...
>>> print 'Abc123'.istitle()
True
>>> # Incomprehensible
...
>>> print 'Abc123P'.istitle()
True
>>> # Comprehensible
...
>>> print 'This is 27Python'.istitle()
False
>>> # Comprehensible
...
>>> print 'ABc123D'.istitle()
False
>>> # Incomprehensible
...
>>> print 'Abc1D'.istitle()
True
```

The documentation of this method is:
"i.e. uppercase characters may only follow uncased characters and lowercase characters only cased ones. Return False otherwise."

I thought it might be some special behavior of String, say, regard '1D' as a decimal '1', but seem it isn't when I printed it out:

```
>>> # Check
...
>>> print 'Abc1D'
Abc1D
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend('Abc1D')
>>> print l
['A', 'b', 'c', '1', 'D']
```

I really cannot understand it, or is this a bug of Python?

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/63f0a1e95d2b/Objects/stringobject.c#l3509).

It's pretty easy to read.  The trick is to realize that numbers are neither upper or lower case, so it causes a reset of the `previous_is_cased` clause.  The same would go for any other non-letter character:  `Abc&D` -> `True`, `ABc&D` -> `False`.

For a more simple explanation, think of your string if you replaced all non-letter characters with spaces.  The result of the translated string will be the same as the result of the original.

Comment: Thank you! The point is that I thought that 'istitle' means 'First letter of the whole string is in upper case'. But now I understand that it means 'each word is capitalized', and the boundary of words are the non-letter character. I wrote the following testing code:

>>> print 'This Is My Title'.istitle()
True
>>> print 'This2Is+My%Title'.istitle()
True
>>> print 'This is My Title'.istitle()
False
>>> print 'This2is*My.Title'.istitle()
False

Answer (score 1):

Take `Abc123P` as example.

Uppercase characters: `A` and `P`. `A` follows nothing while `P` follows a decimal digit which is uncased.

Lowercase characters: `b` and `c`. `b` follows `A` which is cased; `c` follows `b` which is also cased.

Thus, `Abc123P` follows the definition of `istitle()`.